# PHP Session reset on refresh with chrome but stay normal in private navigation

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, model-view-controller, browser-cache

after hours and hours of research I leave it to you.
I am creating an administrator part for my site in MVC architecture with a .htaccess which redirects everything to a main index.php.
I made a classic connection system with a classic hash and some personal ip ban systems to avoid attacks.
Until then everything is normal, I use $_SESSION to keep the connection active and my session_start() is called before the site to be sure to be correctly placed.

the problem is that my session resets each time I refresh the page.
I did a lot of testing and I affirm that it resets well, I know that it is not from PHP, that I did not misuse my session but that chrome or gandi in one way or another another act on my session and break it to me.
For example, when I use chrome in private browsing or firefox or when I'm local I have no problem and the connection goes perfectly well
I haven't seen anyone with a similar problem and I don't know what to do, I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, I reset some cookies, I reset some data but nothing to do, it doesn't change anything.

**EDIT:** here is some more code in order to be more clear on the problem
to show a concrete example of the problem, I made a test file which creates a session and adds 1 each time we refresh the page
on chrome it leaves me at 1 but in private browsing it adds me well +1 at each refresh

**index.php** (of my test project)

```php
<?php

session_start();

// faire un compteur avec $_SESSION["count"] (comment for CoPilot)
if(!isset($_SESSION["count"])){
    $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
}
$_SESSION["count"] += 1;

var_dump($_SESSION["count"]);
```

**EDIT:**
ok, so in private browsing I have this result and $_SESSION["count"] is incremented correctly
[network pass private nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuviY.png)

but in normal browsing $_SESSION["count"] does not increment and 5 JS scripts are added to the request but I don't know where they come from, it may come from some Google Chrome extension but I have already tested without extension and with and it doesn't change anything, I don't understand why $_SESSION["count"] refuses to increment.
[network pass normal nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1XK6.png)

Comment: `$_SESSION` is set by cookie usually its `phpsessid` by default, you may have disabled cookies in the browser as possible cause. Maybe the server configuration is messed up about the `phpsessid` cookie. And because it works based on cookie you have to set it before any output, you said that "session_start() is called before the site", the site may not be the only output, but if that is wrong it wouldnt work anywhere nither firefox or anything. You can inspect the communication per request/responce to see if the cookie is there and the value is correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Inspect the communication, like open devtools in browser, select network tab, refresh page, select the first request from list then select headers tab, here you see request and responce headers, you should see cookie header only in request section with name phpsessid and constant value, do it in normal and private browsing and report what you find out.

Comment: @Kazz I've add some screens and more explains in edit.

Comment: Why haven't you take a look at the headers which are directly responsible for the session behavior as i said in prev comment ? The scripts you find out are most likely extension and i doubt (even when they could) interact with your session cookie. Another question which arise is do you experience same behavior on other websites ? Because why would it be only yours if the extension cause it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by resetting my site's cookies, which I thought I had done, but there might still be special cookies that were hindering the connection to the site, unfortunately I did not look at the data that did that but it must probably come from a bad manipulation on my part.
I can finally log in

thx all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).